# jQuery: Value of an input doesn't save in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't save what I have in my input in a variable. It saves as a blank space or if it's an integer: 0

This is my code:

```js
function attachKeyupEventDescuento(inputElement, i) {
  var cantidad = $('#txt_compras_cantidad' + i).val()
  var costo = $('#txt_compras_costoUni' + i).val()
  total = (cantidad * costo)
  $(inputElement).keyup(function() {
    console.log(total)
    if (inputElement.val() !== '') {
      var descuento = inputElement.val()
      var descuentoTotal = ($('#txt_compras_cantidad' + i).val() * $('#txt_compras_costoUni' + i).val()) - ($('#txt_compras_cantidad' + i).val() * $('#txt_compras_costoUni' + i).val() * (descuento / 100))
      $('#spn_compras_total' + i).text(descuentoTotal.toFixed(2))
      sumarprecioFinal()
    } else {
      $('#spn_compras_total' + i).text(($('#txt_compras_cantidad' + i).val() * $('#txt_compras_costoUni' + i).val()).toFixed(2))
    }
  })
}
```

Let me explain the code:

```
var cantidad = $('#txt_compras_cantidad' + i).val()
var costo = $('#txt_compras_costoUni' + i).val()
```

If I save them in those variables, I get a blank space, but if I use them without saving them in a variable, they work perfectly. Why does it happen?

This function is called from a button that created a new row in my table. The `inputelement` is the current input on which to attach the `keyup` event.

Comment: Can you add and the HTML in a https://jsfiddle.net/ in order the see the whole picture.

Comment: `var descuento = inputElement.val()` should be `var descuento = $(inputElement).val()`

Comment: **Post your HTML**. There is certainly a better way to attach the `keyup` event to your new row (dynamically created) elements, using `.siblings()`, `.parent()` and so on methods.

Comment: I hope you guys would understand the code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/4ygqwmyj/7/), the problem is where i said, @Louys Patrice Bessette damn, really? I asked here for a solution and they told me that keyup is a good way to do id

Comment: I looked at your Fidle... The `keyup` event seems to be attached correctly. **BUT** the `sumarprecioFinal()` function call triggers an error since the function is undefined. Please have a look at the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the updated code

```js
function attachKeyupEventDescuento(inputElement, i) {
  var cantidad = parseInt($('#txt_compras_cantidad' + i).val());
  var costo = parseInt($('#txt_compras_costoUni' + i).val());
  var total = (cantidad * costo)
  $(inputElement).keyup(function() {
    console.log(total)
    if ($(inputElement).val() !== '') {
      var descuento = parseInt($(inputElement).val());
      var descuentoTotal = (cantidad * costo) - (cantidad * costo * (descuento / 100));
      $('#spn_compras_total' + i).text(descuentoTotal.toFixed(2))
      sumarprecioFinal()
    } else {
      $('#spn_compras_total' + i).text((cantidad * costo).toFixed(2))
    }
  })
}
```

When you get value from an input, it's always a string. Try parsing the value of an input.

Comment: No it didn't work :(, i did it before i used the full selector bcoz it wasn't working

Comment: @Christian Here is you solution https://jsfiddle.net/4ygqwmyj/22/ . When you are attaching the `KeyUpEvent`, you shouldn't get the value because that time the value of the input is empty. You should get the value when `jQuery keyUp` actual happended.

Comment: I can't believe, I moved them to be available in the `else` and I didnt realize that they were out of the event, damn, thank you so much for the help